# Time complexity of the for-loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I need to calculate the time complexity of the following loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{

 statements;

}
```

Assuming n = 10,
Is `i < n;` control statement going to run for n time and `i++;` statement for n-1 times? And knowing that `i = 1;` statement is going to run for a unit of time.

Calculating the total time complexity of the three statements in for-loop yields 1+n+n-1 = 2n and the loop with its statements yields 2n+n-1 = 3n-1 = O(n).

Are my calculations correct to this point?

Comment: The time complexity of this loop is `O(n)` if the time complexity of inner statements does not depend on `n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your calculations are correct, a for loop like such would have O(n) notation.

Similarly, you could make a calculation like such:

```
for(int i = 0; i <n*2; i++){
//calculations
}
```

in this case, the for loop would have a big O notation of  O(n^2) (you get the idea)

This loop takes O(n^2) time; math function = n^n This way you can calculate how long your loop need for n 10 or 100 or 1000

This way you can build graphs for loops and such.

as DAle mentioned in the comments the big O notation is not affected by calculations within the loop, only the loop itself.

Comment: are you sure , u mean n*2 and not n^2 ?

Comment: In that case ,wouldn't the time complexity be O(n) only and not O(n^2)